# New Beta Theme Launched

Tags: discussion, beta, site-design

Your site looks a bit different today. Yes, we are getting rid of the 'Sketchy' look and replacing it with a more-polished and finished design for sites in beta.

You can read more about the redesign of our Beta theme on our [blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/).

Please note: This will not affect your "graduation" status in any way. When your site is due for graduation, it will get its final(real) site design and branding.

If you're still seeing the old favicon, please do a hard browser refresh. (Although sometimes it may take Chrome a while to load the new image).

If you see any CSS or styling issues, please report it **[in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126185/new-stack-exchange-beta-theme)** I created on Meta Stack Overflow. It will be easier for me to track all the bug reports there.

Comment: Thanks - this looks much classier.

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our other CMs from last week: [Custom MVM&R design and logo - Information gathering](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2113/67918) :)