# New design launched

Tags: discussion, site-design

As you can see, the new design just went live! At this point, we are done with major revisions to the design (although you can still report CSS/styling bugs by starting a new post and tagging it with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)). Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2127/site-design-and-logo-draft) and for going above and beyond to contribute assets to the design.

I have enjoyed working with you to create this theme. Thank you again for your patience and for being an awesome community. I hope you enjoy the new design!

Comment: I do see one little issue ... the spanner wrenches colors for copper/gold are backwards.

Comment: Agh, will look at this today! For today, gold spanners for everyone.

Comment: I'm not really a regular community member here, but... This design looks so good! I love it. :)

Comment: @Phoebe - I've been brewing on this for a day now and have to say, your choice of colors and how it is all put together ... wow, just really like it. I think it represents the site and the overall take on everything. I personally really love it all. Thank you for putting it together as well as listening to us about what might work. It's a really nice job.

Comment: I'm going to pat my own back here ... I think the wrenches for badges look awesome and are very much reflect the site and what we are about. Plus them being unique makes things awesome :o) (Yes, this is being a bit self serving, but I dig them!)

Comment: Thanks, @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2! I had fun making this theme and your feedback was extremely helpful. I did go into a rabbit hole reading and learning about all the different types of wrenches :)

Answer (score 11):

WOOT! I think it looks pretty darn spiffy! The spanners (aka: combination wrenches) look great as badges. Very unique! The color scheme and background look great. I don't know about anyone else, but I'm very happy! TY you for all your hard work, Phoebe, as well as for putting up with all of my suggestions :o)

Comment: I think it looks great too! Feels like we're a _real_ SE site now!

Answer (score 1):

I have been away at a conference since the 8th - came back to the new look and I love it. It really stands out in my Chrome tabs, and is very clean on all my different screens, both fixed and mobile.

Awesome work!